# how to let a table drop down on click with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, datatable

When using a `<p>` my script works. When I replace this with a table, it doesn't want to follow the rules of my script. The table is supposed to drop down under a button when clicked.

Im using php to get information from the database, but this shouldnt interfere as the data shows correctly in the table. I have tried to put the table in the div. I have tried different kind of style.height/style.display in the javascript.

this works properly

```
        <h1 type="button" class="stelling">Where  the sun?

        </h1>
    </div>
    <div id="p1" class="data">
        Here comes the sun!
    </div>
```

but when I try to put a table in

```
<div class="stellingen";>
    <div type="button" id="btn1" class="stelling-wrapper">
        <img src="images/button.svg" alt="Show more..." class="btn" id="bton">
        <p type="button" class="stelling">
    </div>
<?php
    $sql2="SELECT * FROM stellingen WHERE stelling_ID=1;";
    $records2 =  mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
    $recordscheck2 = mysqli_num_rows($records2);

    if ($recordscheck2 > 0){
        while ($stellingen = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records2)){
            echo "<p>".@$stellingen['Stelling']."</p>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Here is where I use the same id, just like the example that worked, i also tried with table id=p1

```
<div id="p1">
    <table id="tabel" class="data">
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Source</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>

<?php
$sql1="SELECT * FROM stelling WHERE stelling_iD=1;";
$records1 =  mysqli_query($con, $sql1);
$recordscheck = mysqli_num_rows($records1);

if ($recordscheck > 0){
    while ($stelling = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records1)){
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".@$stelling['Title']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".@$stelling['Source']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".@$stelling['Wheight']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".@$stelling['Date']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
?>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The javascript

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var a = false;

    document.getElementById('btn1').onclick = function (){
        if(a== false){
            document.getElementById('p1').style.height = "auto";
            a =true;
        }else{
            document.getElementById('p1').style.height = "0px";
            a =false;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I expect a div wit my table to drop down when clicked on the button

Comment: Please dont hide errors using the `@` in code like `@$stelling['Title']` If there is an error in there, lets see it and fix it

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Are you sure the table is in the HTML?

Comment: @RiggsFolly If I take away the ```@``` it gives me an error: undefined index. And thanks, I will look into the coding standard

Comment: Which line gives you the error

Comment: @michel Yes, its in the html, its just after the closing php tag

Comment: @RiggsFolly ```echo "<td>".@$stelling['Date']."</td>";```

Comment: I mean: in the actual HTML in your **browser** (F12 and search for it).

Comment: Then you dont have a `Date` column in the `stelling` table, or maybe its called `date` Either way, check the schema for the columns that do exists in that table

Comment: @Michel Yoou're right, its not in the html in the browser

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you, that actually  does improve my code.. although it doesn't fix the problem

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, you were correct, it had a different name. It does work now. I also changes the ```style.display```in my javacript to switch to auto. Thank you